# ReactJS, Redux : How do I return an array of items in my STATE?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having trouble getting back then 1 array item in the results returned from an api call.

This is the function in actions.

```
  followCheckList:function(userId){
    for(var i= 0; i < userId.length;i++ ){
      return{
        types: [C.FOLLOW_CHECK_LIST, C.FOLLOW_CHECK_LIST_SUCCESS, C.FOLLOW_CHECK_LIST_FAIL],
        promise: (client)=> client.get(`/graph/me/follows/${userId[i]}`)
        .then(result => {
          return result.id;      
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

My reducers

```
    case C.FOLLOW_CHECK_LIST:
        return{
            ...state,
            follow_check_list:null,
            error:false,
        };
    case C.FOLLOW_CHECK_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return{
            ...state,
            //break here
            error:false,                
            follow_check_list: action.result
        };

    case C.FOLLOW_CHECK_LIST_FAIL:
        return{
            ...state,
            follow_check_list:false,
            error:action.error,
        };

    default: return state || {loading: false,
                                    loaded: null,
                                    list_loaded: null};
}
```

I'm expecting 2 results from `follow_check_list : action.result` so in my state I should see

```
follow_check_list : Array[2].
       0: item1,
       1: item2
```

But instead I see :

```
follow_check_list : Array[1].
       0: item1,
```

**update**
My component. arrayIds has 2 items.

```
let arrayIds=[];
const FollowStatus = React.createClass ({

    componentWillMount(){
        arrayIds.push(this.props.status);
    },
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.followCheckList(arrayIds)
    },
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Where is "followers_checklist" supposed to be coming from?

Comment: its inside the function. If its undefined, then I create it.  I did this to prevent the variable from instantiating a second time when the function is called more than once

Comment: And what does your "result" look like in the AJAX callback?  Is it a single object?  Because all you're doing is pushing that one object into the array...

Comment: yeah it's single object.  What should I do ?

Comment: Well, if your response is one item, how/why are you expecting two items in the array you're dispatching?

For that matter, what does your action dispatching look like?

Comment: Oh, wait, you're using one of those addon libs that dispatches actions automatically based on promises, aren't you.

So yeah... you're returning an array with one item.  Why would you expect it to have two?

Comment: This is impossible to diagnose without seeing your middleware that's intercepting the thunk actions.

Comment: Hey I updated the post.   userIds is an array and it has 2 items in it. So I call the api twice

Comment: Is your action in the reducer getting called twice?  I believe what you are seeing is the last call.  It does not look like you are merging the follow_check_list, so each time it gets called it is just setting it to the newest value.

Comment: @NormCrandall thats exactly whats happening

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your followCheckList function has a "return" statement in the "for" loop: the function execution stops on the first iteration, which must be why you only get "item1".

Comment: @joejoeso did you check if this assumption is the reason behind your problem?